# Control mysql arrays with button

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery-mobile, button

I want a button to show the next array in MySQL. This is what I have so far; I just want to to show the next one with a loop if possible.

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","test1");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM problems");

  $i = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $array[$i] = $row['problem'];
    $i++;
  }
  echo $array[1];

  mysqli_close($con);
?>

<center>
  <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
     <button data-icon="arrow-l">Back</button>
     <button data-icon="arrow-l">Forward</button>
```

Comment: Why not just use table to show the data?

Comment: What is the next array?

Comment: thats what i had originally but it i want it to show the info nicely

Comment: What do you mean fabio .... it starts at 0 and people will always be adding

Comment: People are going to be submitting problems and on this page it will show all the different problems with people going through all them with the buttons

Comment: So, only one "problem" should be shown at a time? Not sure what purpose the next/previous serve, as-is, since every single problem gets pulled with your current query.

Comment: yeah only one should be shown and right now its showing the first one just need the buttons to show the next

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (quick example):

```
$pos = is_numeric($_GET['pos']) ? $_GET['pos'] : 0;

if ($pos < 0)
 $pos = 0;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","test1");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM problems ORDER BY id LIMIT $pos, 1");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if (!empty($row)) {

  echo "<div>My problem data: " . $row['some_field'] . "</div>";   

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
      <center><div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <button data-icon="arrow-l"><a href="this.php?pos=<?php echo $pos-1 ?>">Back</a></button>
        <button data-icon="arrow-l"><a href="this.php?pos=<?php echo $pos+1 ?>">Forward</a></button>
```

Downside of this is that request to server is made evry time when you click next or previous.. other option to do this is with javascript and hidden elements.

Comment: this kinda makes sense but doesn't what is $pos doing ?

Comment: Set the index of wanted row (where to limit the query).. order your query by id or what ever is your main index.

Comment: the `LIMIT` in sql limits the number of row requested from database. Try learning the basic sql syntax.